# Filter records from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to divide a model records into two categories `inc and dec`:

I begin by filtering my records like below:

```
Model.where.not('first_value = 0 AND second_value = 0')
     .where.not('first_value = second_value')
```

So I can write the scope.

```
scope :filter -> do
                where.not('first_value = 0 AND second_value = 0')
                .where.not('first_value = second_value')
end
```

After getting the filtered results I need to divide the records into two parts.

`Increased; Decreased`

But the problem is that I don't know how to add this condition to filter my results, (a solution can be to loop over each filtered record, and return a hash with two array one for `inc` and one for `dec`, and each array will contain the `id of the record`), it will work like this but I think the solution is not the best one.

```
  if first_value == 0 || second_value == 0
    first_value > second_value ? increased : decreased
  else
    first_value > second_value ? decreased : increased
  end
```

How can I filter the records, so when the user will select increased, only the increased records will be displayed; or the other way around.

[Update] How I do it now:

```
def compare
  records = self.reduce // the scope from above
  ids = {inc: [], dec: []}
  records.each do |r|
    if r.first_value == 0 || second_value == 0
      r.first_position > second_value ? ids[:inc] << r.keyword_id : ids[:dec] << r.keyword_id
    else
      r.first_position > second_value ? ids[:dec] << r.keyword_id : ids[:inc] << r.keyword_id
    end
  end
  ids
end
```

And after that based on the param passed, I reload the model `where(keyword_id: ids[:inc])` or `where(keyword_id: ids[:dec])`

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the logic that you presented here:

```
if first_value == 0 || second_value == 0
  first_value > second_value ? increased : decreased
else
  first_value > second_value ? decreased : increased
end
```

You could write your scopes as follows:

```
scope :increased -> do
  where("((first_value = 0 or second_value = 0) and (first_value > second_value)) or ((first_value != 0 and second_value != 0) and (first_value <= second_value))")
end
scope :decreased -> do
  where("((first_value = 0 or second_value = 0) and (first_value <= second_value)) or ((first_value != 0 and second_value != 0) and (first_value > second_value))")
end
```

This could be cleaned up a bit but it should work as is.

Comment: This works great, thanks, also I had to add the filter scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :filtered -> do
    where.not('first_value = 0 AND second_value = 0')
   .where.not('first_value = second_value')
end

scope :increased -> do
   filtered.where('first_value < second_value')
end

scope :decreased -> do
   filtered.where('first_value > second_value')
end
```

Model.increased would then return all the filtered records that have increased.

Does that help?

Edit:

```
scope :increased -> do
  User.where("(first_value = 0 or second_value = 0 and first_value > second_value) or (first_value < second_value)")
end
```

Comment: Not really, if the first_value or second_value is 0 then `first_value > second_value ? increased : decreased` else first_value > second_value ? decreased : increased

Comment: I don't think you need to go through that whole process of finding all the IDs of the ones that have increased, storing them in a separate array, and then do another query to get all records from that array. Where you do where(keyword_id: ids[:dec]), that should return the same records as the scope Model.decreased. Try Model.decreased.pluck(:id) to see if the array of IDs it returns matches your array ids[:dec] that you manually create.

Comment: I already did all that, but the results are different :(, the only way that I know to get the correct results is doing as I did in my example.

Comment: Well I think the 2 methods should produce the same results - up to you whether you want to debug it any further. From what I can see, those scopes (or something very similar) are far simpler and are exactly what you're looking for ... and they do away with about 15 lines of code as well.

Comment: It will not produce the same results, because when one of the values is 0 there is a different condition, check the output for the conditions, thx for the effort.

Comment: How about the revised 'increase' scope?

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on how to pass the conditional code from ruby to sql, so you can have the `increased` or `decreased` collections in a single query to the database.

Notice that in your first filter the condition `where.not('first_value = 0 AND second_value = 0')`is redundant, as you are already filtering out the rows with the same value on both columns:

```
scope :filter, -> do
  where.not("first_value = second_value")
end

scope :inc, -> do
  query = <<-SQL
    ((first_value = 0 OR second_value = 0) AND first_value > second_value)
    OR
    ((first_value != 0 AND second_value != 0) AND first_value < second_value)
  SQL
  filter.where(query)
end

scope :dec, -> do
  query = <<-SQL
    ((first_value = 0 OR second_value = 0) AND first_value < second_value)
    OR
    ((first_value != 0 AND second_value != 0) AND first_value > second_value)
  SQL
  filter.where(query)
end
```

There is a great amount of repetition that you could refactor.

That being said, it is a bit misleading that you call a scope 'increased' and it is returning this values `(first: 2, second: 5)` and also `(first: 3, second: 0)`. Same thing for the 'decreased' scope. I understand that this question is a simplification of your real business case, but still, be careful :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your problem a lot if you denormalize your database by adding an extra `increased` booelan field and keep it updated through callbacks.

example:

```
before_save :set_increased

def set_increased
  self.increased = first_value < second_value
end
```

that way you would be able to chain an `increased` or `decreased` scope to your filter

```
scope :increased -> { where(increased: true) }
scope :decreased -> { where(increased: false) }
```

this is the simplest approach. If you expand it to integrate your exact query needs inside the callback you will end up using only that filter. With this in mind, adding an index to the new field will help even more.

#### Update

If as stated in the comment you need 3 comparisons (1,2), (2,3), (3,4) then I think that you can expand the above mentioned technique and create 3 extra columns with their indexes (if needed) and modify your model callback logic accordingly.

Now if you want something more complex (eg random comparisons on the 4 (or more) fields) it would be better to keep the model clean and create a wrapper module to handle your query generators. Maybe using a tiny DSL.

Comment: what if I want to compare multiple columns,(third_value, fourth_value) should I store that into an array and have [1, 1, 0, 1]? or should I create more columns?

Comment: I think this is different from the original question, but check for my update.

Comment: I am not a postgres expert but perhaps  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON can save you some trouble if you end up storing the values on an array.